# Unknown options when parsing to DDB

Tags: shell, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to put an item to DynamoDB using CLI, but I'm getting an error: Unknown options: {, "S":, "do_something", },, "CreatedOn":, {, "N":, "201412250053", }, }, "TestRunId":

```
ENTRY='{ "TestRunId": { "S": "do_something" }, "CreatedOn": {"N": "201412250053"} }'
JSON=$(echo ${ENTRY} | jq .)
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name TestResultsDDBTable --item ${JSON} --region ${REGION}
```

Comment: You should double quotes variables: `echo "${ENTRY}" | jq .` and `--item "${JSON}"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it in windows cmd, try this:

> aws dynamodb put-item --table-name TestResultsDDBTable --item "{
>   \"TestRunId\": { \"S\": \"do_something\" }, \"CreatedOn\": {\"N\":
>   \"201412250053\"} }" --region ${REGION}

I was bothered by this question for one afternoon, :)
and I finally found a solution in here: https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-dynamodb/discussion/-KUX8EQjmN7F2pNKvoWW/when-i-am-trying-to-run-below-command-aws-dynamodb-put-item-table-name-weatherst